# How to clear all cart items in magento cart (In all PCs from all over world)

Tags: magento-1.9

When i run a script then clear cart items from all **PCs** which already added a cart item(s).

Comment: I got the solution run below query in sql
`DELETE FROM sales_flat_quote WHERE is_active = 1;`

**is_active = 0** means those quotes have been converted into orders, i.e. customer has placed order for those quotes.
**is_active = 1** means quotes that have not been ordered, i.e. quotes present in the shopping cart of customers

Comment: Yes, it's work for me.

Answer (score 1):

try below code.

```
protected $quoteFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    ....
}

$quoteCollection = $this->quoteFactory->create()->getCollection()
          ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);       

foreach ($quoteCollection as $item) {
    $item->delete();    
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Run the following Query :

> Delete FROM `quote` WHERE is_active=1 AND reserved_order_id IS NULL

Now run following command from Your Magento Root directory :

> Truncate persistent_session

Comment: In magento database there are no any **`quote`** table 
There are only quote related 7 tables.
1. sales_flat_quote
2. sales_flat_quote_item
3. sales_flat_quote_item_option
4. sales_flat_quote_address
5. sales_flat_quote_address_item
6. sales_flat_quote_payment
7. sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate